# capture user id when login and save user id based on operations

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.6

I need to capture login user and when i add question i need to save the corresponding user id in the questions table.i'm getting user id when i login but it is not saving in the question table

Controller with store function

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
        $last_que = Question::orderBy('question_id', 'desc')->first();
        if ($last_que != null) {
            $old_queId = $last_que->question_id;
            $old_queId = $old_queId + 1;
        } else {
            $old_queId = 1;
        }
        $qorder=$request->input('order');
        $question=new Question();
        $quest=$question->checkDuo($qorder);
        if(count($quest)==0)
        {
            $que=Question::create([
                'question'=>$request->input('question'),
                'question_id'=>$old_queId,
                'question_type'=>$request->input('qtype'),
                'question_schedul'=>$request->input('qschedule'),
                'created_user_id'=>Session::get('created_id'),
                'order_no'=>$request->input('order')
            ]);
            if($que)
            {
                return redirect()->route('questions.index')->with('success', 'Successfully saved');
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect()->back()->with('fail', 'Unable to save..! Entry with same order no. already exist');

        }
    }
```

in Login index file this is i used capture the user id

```
<?php
if (!empty($id)) {
    Session::put('created_id', $id);
}
?>
```

Login controller

```
 public function postSignIn(Request $request)
    {

        if (Auth::attempt(['username' => $request['username'], 'password' => $request['password']])) {
            $user = DB::table('users')->where([['username', '=', $request['username']], ['status', '=', '0']])->first();
            $user_id = $user->user_id;


            return redirect()->route('dashboard', $user_id)->with('message', 'State saved correctly!!!');
        } else {
            return redirect()->back();
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get user ID. use something like this.

```
Auth:user()->id;
```

Or you can use

```
Session::getId();
```

Comment: could you post your login controller

Comment: id field exist in your database

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170418/discussion-between-rahul-shrivastava-and-abhijith).

Comment: yes it worked,it was semicolon missing in the migration

Answer (score 0):

Change this line,

```
'created_user_id'=>Session::get('created_id'),
```

To,

```
'created_user_id'=>Auth::id(),
```

Comment: Let me check @arun

Comment: its'not working   this what i did to capture user id in login                  
    <?php
if (!empty($id)) {
    Session::put('created_id', $id);
}
?>

Answer (score 0):

You used $user_id

```
return redirect()->route('dashboard', $user_id)->with('message', 'State saved correctly!!!');
```

Than asking:

```
if (!empty($id)) {
```

This $id will be always empty so use:

```
<?php
if (!empty($user_id)) {
    Session::put('created_id', $user_id);
}
?>
```